# Edit children in scrollview where scrollview is a child of relativelayout in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview, android-scrollview

In my xml hierarchy, I have the root element as a `RelativeLayout` and then a `Scrollview` as a child. That `ScrollView` then has a `RelativeLayout` with views inside it.

My problem is that I cannot edit the contents in the `ScrollView` as the design view of Android Studio doesn't show the entire `ScrollView`. I've tried the toggle viewport render mode button but that doesn't change anything (note: my `ScrollView`'s fillviewport is true as well.

Is there a way I can see everything in my `ScrollView` where the `ScrollView` is a child of a `RelativeLayout` in Android Studio's design view?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well.

If you have a view hierarchy like...

```
RelativeLayout (root)  
  --> ScrollView
    --> RelativeLayout
      --> Views (e.g. Buttons, TextViews, etc.)
```

...I change the above layout to something like...

```
RelativeLayout (root)
  --> Include
```

...where my include tag is referencing another XML layout...

```
ScrollView
  --> RelativeLayout
    --> Views (e.g. Buttons, TextViews, etc.)
```

In Android Studio's preview, the first XML layout with the `<include>` tag should show (part of the complete) layout on the device.

The second XML layout, with the `ScrollView` as its root should show you all of the `View`s.

As far as I know, there is no other way around this, unfortunately - and I would love to see an alternative solution if there is one.